# Register an image to a stack of images with C++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I have one image and a stack of images.  I need to register the one image to the stack of images with a 3d registration translation, rotation.  I know I must use rigid.  I use distance map as a measure of match but I can not manage how to make the registration.

If I take after segmentation the points of interest of one image and search for it in map of stack I do not take something.  Has anyone any idea?

Comment: Are you using some image processing framework?

Comment: No .I write the program from the beginning .I made one that manages two stacks and makes the registation .But now i have one image and a stack and i can not find a way to make the registration of the image

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant snippets, no-one can understand what you are talking about if it's all custom code.

Comment: The thought of the 3d registration is simple .I use the one dataset as reference and the other as float, i make a segmenation ,i use rigid and distance map as a MOM. And i take the rotation and translation for the registration .The problem is that now i have one image and a dataset and i can not make the registration this way.I need some ideas.Thanks

Comment: This is all very clear in your head certainly, but I don't know who else can understand your issue. What does "make a registration" mean?

Comment: Are you talking about [image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) or [printing registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_registration)? Or something completely different? I ask because I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Make a registration means to have an image as reference and an other image "same" with the other one but translated and with some roatation. With registration you search for translation and rotation that makes the second image "similar " with the first.

Comment: How are the images in the stack related ?

Answer (score 0):

Extract SIFT features from your image library and your current image. Check the current image against each of the library images by doing a RANSAC estimation of the camera matrix needed to project the current image onto the library image. If you can find a reasonable transform matrix, for reasonable RANSAC parameters, you can consider the image a registered match.

Comment: Do you know any software with which i can make this steps?

Comment: MATLAB has all the tools you will need besides a SIFT feature extractor. C++ has loads of libraries for doing this too. Check out OpenCV, Shogun toolbox, etc.